# jQuery 1.8.2 - how do I grab an option from a select with only the text?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-1.8

Simply put, using this:

```
<select id="Test">
    <option value="1">ABC</option>
    <option value="2">DEF</option>
</select>
```

How can I use jQuery to get `option[value="2"]` using only "DEF" - Keep in mind I am using 1.8.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$('#Test option:contains("DEF")')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gYC3A/)

Note that `:contains()` is a wildcard search. If you need an exact match, I think you'll just need to iterate or filter the options and check the `text()`. Here's one possibility:

http://jsfiddle.net/YuK2K/

```
console.log(getOptionByText('Test', 'DEF'));

function getOptionByText(id, value) {
    return $('#' + id).find('option').filter(function() {
       return $(this).text() == value; 
    });
}
```

Comment: Not quite... This will fail if the select is like this `<select id="Test">
    <option value="1">DEFasfdas</option>
    <option value="2">ABC</option>
    <option value="3">DEF</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains` if you are sure that no other option that appears prior contains that value. Note that **contains does a wildcard match** not an exact match. Instead you can do this way to do an exact match.

```
$('#Test option').filter(function () {
    return this.innerHTML === 'DEF'
}).val();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujjuN/)**

Answer (score 1):

Does it help?

```
$( '#Test option' ).each( function() {
    if ( $( this ).html() == 'DEF' ) {
        alert( $( this ).val() );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select option:contains('ABC')")
```

here is example - http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/7fF7M/